# Address of pointer

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in programming. I have a problem that i can't find an understandable answer by myself. I want to  find address of pointer by using C++ and C, but two result are different although they have some similar number. Are they still same address ?

```
adress of g is :0018F9C4
address of g is: 0018F9D3
```

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char g = 'z';
    char*p;

    p = &g;

    std::cout << "adress of g is :" << &p;
    printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
}
```

Comment: where is the ampersand in the printf statement?

Comment: When you do `&g` you get a pointer to `g`. What do you think happens when you do `&p`? (Hint: You don't get a pointer to `g`)

Comment: `void main()` is wrong. Use `int main()`

Answer (score 7):

This line display address *of* `p`

```
std::cout << "address of p is :" << &p;
```

This line display address *in* `p`, ie address *of* `g`

```
printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
```

It's normal to have different result.

Try

```
std::cout << "address of g is :" << static_cast<void*>(p);
printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
```

Comment: p is of type `char*`. You may have to cast it to `void*` so that the ostream does not interpret it as a c string

Answer (score 1):

On the line with std::cout you print out &p...the address of p itself
On the printf line you print out the value of p..no &p

That's different of course.

You should use

```
std::cout << "adress of g is :" << (void *)p;
printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
```

And why are you mixing cout and printf?

Answer (score 1):

This example may show it in a better way:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char g = 'z';
    char*p = &g;
    std::cout << "adress of g is :" << static_cast<void*>(p);
    std::cout << "\nadress of p is :" << &p;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://cpp.sh/76a3f)

`static_cast<void*>(p)` is converting a char* to void* for historical purpose. `char*` is a pointer but it was used as `string` in C. So the `<< operator` will deal with it as a value not as a pointer. So the trick here is to convert to another pointer type so the `<< operator` will print its actual value which is the address of `g`.

Now, `&p` is the address of `p` not the address of `g`. In other word it is the address of the place that the address of `g` is stored in.

> ```
> (g=='z') is True
> (&g==p) is True
> (*p==g) is True
>
> (&p==p) is False
> (&g=&p) is False
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that ***Address of a pointer*** and ***Address of what pointer is pointing to*** are 2 different thing.

`&p --> Address of "P"
p --> Address of "g" what pointer is pointing to`

Answer (score 0):

Answer: **No, they are not the same address**, This is clear as the values are different - A program's memory-address pointing to the same location will *always* be the same.

Explanation:
(tl;dr - `&p` is the address of `p`, not the address of `g`)

`char g = 'z'` Does exactly what you'd expect - creates a *literal constant*, and ensures it will be somewhere in memory during your programs execution.
`char*p; p = &g;` (which can be shortened to `char*p = &g`) One again, doesn't what you expect, providing the memory-address of the data `g` into a variable called `p` ~ Take note however, that `p` is **also a variable, and thus must be held in memory!**

The error in your program is during the last two lines of execution:

```
std::cout << "adress of g is :" << &p;
printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
```

The first line (using std::cout) will present **the address of `p`**, As stated previously, `p` is a pointer, but a pointer is no different from any other variable - it is simply data stored in memory. As such you are at this point creating a *temporary* **pointer to a pointer** - AKA `char **`.

The second line however, does what you expect, outputting the memory-address stored in `p`.
A correct program would be as follows.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char g = 'z';
    char*p = &g;


    std::cout << "adress of g is :" << (int)p; //optionally for C++11 use static_cast<int>
    printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
}
```

You could also try using the debugger on this example!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdint>
void main()
{
    char g = 'z';
    char*p = &g;

    //THIS ASSUMES 32-bit! Note on 64bit systems a pointer is 64-bit, (you can conclude the result for an 8bit or 16bit addressing model)
uint32_t P_value = (uint32_t)p;

    std::cout << "adress of g is :" << P_value;
    printf("\naddress of g is: %p", p);
}
```